# ¿ Cómo guardar valor de un select a un <input>?

Tags: php, javascript

Soy nuevo en `PHP`, de `JavaScript` no sé mucho. Este es mi código

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" name="idArticulo" 
  id="idArticulo"  value="<?php echo $row["idArticulo"]; ?> "/>

<select class="form-control" name ="sel_quantity" id="sel_quantity" 
    onChange="mostrarValor(this.value);">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="quantity"  id="quantity<?php echo $row["idArticulo"]; ?>" 
  class="form-control" value="1" />
```

Ahora el codigo javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var mostrarValor = function(x) {                            
            //almacenar en la caja de texto             
            document.getElementById('quantity').value=x;
        }
</script>
```

El problema es que cuando selecciono un elemento del `select`, la caja de texto no recibe nada.

Comment: Tu problema es que la id `quantity` no existe en el contexto, `id="quantity<?php echo $row["idArticulo"]; ?>"` esto a mi parecer deberia ser  `id="quantity"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo, necesitas que el ID dependa del `idArticulo` que traes de la base de datos, ¿cierto? En ese caso, te presento esta posibilidad con el **mínimo de cambios** a tu código:

```
<input type="text" name="quantity"  id=<?php echo "quantity".$row["idArticulo"]; ?>" class="form-control" value="1" />
```

Ten en cuenta que si haces esto, en tu función en Javascript debes de saber tambien como sera el ID de este input antes de tratar de asignarle un nuevo valor. Te pongo un ejemplo de como deberia verse:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var id_unico = "xxx";     
    var mostrarValor = function(x) {                            
            //almacenar en la caja de texto             
            document.getElementById('quantity'+id_unico).value=x;

        }

</script>
```

En donde `id_unico` deberia tener lo mismo que tiene `$row["idArticulo"]`.

Comment: y en id_unico = "xxx" que valor colocaría?

Comment: me quedo de esta manera:    <script type="text/javascript">
  var id_unico = "Z0000703741005024077";
  var mostrarValor = function(x) {       
        document.getElementById('quantity'+id_unico).value=x;
   }
 </script>

Comment: @Hermann Como mencione, `id_unico` deberia tener el mismo valor que `$row["idArticulo"]`. La unica forma de tener este valor en Javascript es con Ajax. Si tienes preguntas de Ajax hay bastante informacion en este sitio o bien puedes hacer otra pregunta porque es un tema completamente diferente.

Comment: @Hermann pues me parece correcto lo que te ha quedado. Espero te funcione. P.D. Si estas usando JQuery, es mejor que hagas todo con JQuery. Mezclar JS y JQuery podria confundirte y hacer tu código, literalmente, imposible de mantener. Tambien, aunque no lo mencione, mezclar PHP con HTML no es la mejor practica. :D

Comment: Y @Hermann no olvides marcar la respuesta que mas te sirva como aceptada (no necesariamente la mia), para esta y todas tus preguntas. Es una buena forma de mantener el sitio con calidad y ordenado.

Comment: Funciona, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Veo dos problemas en tu código:

- 1. No tienes bien cerradas las comillas en tu `input`, ya que estás cerrando las comillas dobles antes de hora, tendrías que combinar comillas simples y comillas dobles.

     Quedaría así:

     ```
     id="quantity<?php echo $row['idArticulo']; ?>"
                                 ^          ^
     ```
- 2. No estás pasandole el `$row['idArticulo']` a la función, por lo que estás intentando referenciar un elemento (`quantity`) que no existe.

     Para tener un código totalmente dinámico tendrías que pasarle este valor a la función y de esta manera poder referenciarlo después.

Te dejo un ejemplo de tu código simplificado y poniendo únicamente `quantity` como id del `input`.

```js
var mostrarValor = function(x) {           
     document.getElementById('quantity').value=x;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" name ="sel_quantity" id="sel_quantity" 
    onChange="mostrarValor(this.value);">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="quantity"  id="quantity" 
  class="form-control" value="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

El `id` de tu input no es `'quantity'` sino `quantity<?php echo $row["idArticulo"]; ?>`. Mejor en lugar de depender del id puedes pasarle `this` a `mostrarValor` y ubicar el inout relativo a ese `<select>`. Por otro lado no veo la necesidad de alamcenar la función en una variable.

Ten en cuenta que este código depende de un `<div>` padre que representa a tu fila dentro de la tabla que estás haciendo, solo adáptalo al código que tengas y agrégale los tags de PHP necesarios que quité para que funcione la demo aquí.

```js
function mostrarValor(select) {
  select.parentNode.querySelector("input[name=quantity]").value = select.value;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="hidden" name="idArticulo" id="idArticulo" />

  <select class="form-control" name="sel_quantity" id="sel_quantity" onChange="mostrarValor(this)">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
 </select>

  <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control" value="1" />
</div>
```